# Typehead.js returns unwanted value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm happy to get the whole thing working, but there is one last bug. When I click/hover on the filtered list, the value in the search fiels shows an object and not the selected value.

```
$('#searchbox').typeahead({
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 3,
    remote: {
      url: '/typeahead?s=%QUERY',
      filter: function(parsedResponse) {

            return _.map(parsedResponse, function(res){
                return {
                    value: res, /// I need this object for further functions, but I don't want this to be displayed in the searchbox....
                }
            });

      }


    },
    template: function (data) {
            return '<p>'+data.value.name+'</p>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Per the docs, template is a hash, not a function. https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md

Comment: THx for the answer, but what do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets), `template` is a hash, not a function. More specifically, the dataset can support different types of templates. The one you're looking for is the `suggestion` template.

Soo... your call and options object would look something like this (untested):

```
$('#searchbox').typeahead({
    limit: 10,
    minLength: 3,
    remote: {
        url: '/typeahead?s=%QUERY',
        // ..filter and other stuff ..
    template: {
        // Modifies what's displayed in the suggestion list
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<p>'+data.value.name+'</p>';
        }
    },
    // Modifies what's displayed in the input after a suggestion is selected
    displayKey: function(data) {
         return data.value.name;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but the searchbox still shows [object Object]

Comment: I know it's much (much) later, but it was a partial misunderstanding of what you were originally asking. The `suggestion` template only handles the suggestions list. You'll also want to use the `display` option. I'll edit to include.